# I need the regular expression for this string

Tags: regex

Can anyone please help me get the regex for this expression:

version="X1" android-versionCode="Y1" ios-CFBundleVersion="Z1"

Where X1, Y1, and Z1 could be anything, such as series of numbers and periods, in fact it shouldn't matter.

All I care about is finding the whole string, I don't care about the values of X1, Y1 and Z1

I need this so I can do a replace using the regex to something like this:
version="X2" android-versionCode="Y2" ios-CFBundleVersion="Z2"

Comment: And what have you tried to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just accept anything that is not a quote.

```
version="([^"]*)" android-versionCode="([^"]*)" ios-CFBundleVersion="([^"]*)"
```

Comment: You may need to get a little more detailed if the attributes might come in any order or be separated by random white space.